# SQL (Access) Not returning correct records

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, record

Having an issue with this:

> Return all rm records whose cp.date_registered is NOT registered after 01/01/2013

I've been working variations on this to try to get the job done:

```
 SELECT rm.fname, rm.lname, rm.dob, rm.dod, cp.date_registered
 FROM rm INNER JOIN cp ON rm.member_id = cp.member_id
 WHERE cp.date_registered <= #01/01/2013#
 AND NOT cp.date_registered  > #01/01/2013#
 AND rm.dod Is Null;
```

So basically I just need a few fields from rm records where the date registered isn't after 01/01/2013. I thought it'd be simple, but apparently I need a little help.

Right now that code returns

1. All records with a date registered < 01/01/2013, even if registered after date. I need to exclude those records.
2. Multiple records for each person. I just need 1 record per person if criteria is met, I don't care about dates.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT rm.fname, rm.lname, rm.dob, rm.dod, cp.date_registered
FROM rm INNER JOIN cp ON rm.member_id = cp.member_id
WHERE cp.date_registered <= #01/01/2013#
AND rm.dod Is Null;
```

Using `DISTINCT` should get a single record (if I understand your requirements correctly :))

Comment: Thanks, solves my first problem. I'm only getting one record per instance of the criteria. But it's still returning records of people that have registered after 01/01/2013 (Because they also registered before then as well). I'm looking towards the NOT EXISTS keyword now and will update if I find an answer.

Comment: Is the `cp.date_registered` field the date they registered.

Comment: @Dan looks like you already answered your own question :)  I did misread your question the first time but it looks like you found your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. This will return records from rm that do not have a registration date after 01/01/2013 on cp.

```
 SELECT rm.fname, rm.lname, rm.dob, rm.dod
 FROM rm
 WHERE rm.dod Is Null
 AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT cp.date_registered
    FROM cp
    WHERE rm.member_id = cp.member_id
    AND cp.date_registered >= #01/01/2013#);
```

Also, It will only return one record per occurrence, no need for DISTINCT.